# Laravel language switch returns 404 on one page only

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, language-switching

So I have implemented language switching for my application, across majority of the pages it works well, however there is one page where switching language returns 404. When I switch language, route looks like this e.g. password/lang/en followed by 404 error, but if I remove password from the url tab then I get redirected with back with language being switched.

My translations are placed in resources/lang/language_name

Route for switching language:

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'Localization\LocalizationController@index');
```

Route where 404 is thrown when switch(this is from Laravel's auth layer):

```
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
```

Controller:

```
 public function index($locale)
    {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        //storing the locale in session to get it back in the middleware
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Middleware/Localization.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I have no idea where to look at and wasn't being able to find that anyone has encountered this problem.

**EDIT**
If I add password to switching route:

```
Route::get('password/lang/{locale}', 'Localization\LocalizationController@index');
```

It works then, but obviously other routes wouldn't, my question would be do I leave it like this, 2 separate routes:

```
Route::get('/lang/{locale}', 'Localization\LocalizationController@index');
Route::get('password/lang/{locale}', 'Localization\LocalizationController@index');
```

or there is a better option here?

Comment: Post some code, at least the route code which is belongs to 404

Comment: Seems like you called the wrong route somewhere, but we can't give you any more info until you provide some code (routes, controllers...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad, edited the question